# Angular 2 Reactive Form Error - TypeError: this.form.get is not a function

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am using Angular 2 RC 5 with following:

- esnext
- webpack
- reactive form

I have built a simple test form and I am getting following error in the browser console:

```
zone.js:461Unhandled Promise rejection: EXCEPTION: Error in ./FormComponent class FormComponent - inline template:4:25
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: this.form.get is not a function
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
TypeError: this.form.get is not a function
    at FormGroupDirective.addControl (https://tahseen.github.io/angular2-reactive-form-webpack-esnext/loads.bundle.js:35832:31)
    at FormControlName.ngOnChanges (https://tahseen.github.io/angular2-reactive-form-webpack-esnext/loads.bundle.js:35650:33)
    at DebugAppView._View_FormComponent0.detectChangesInternal (FormComponent.ngfactory.js:230:55)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (https://tahseen.github.io/angular2-reactive-form-webpack-esnext/loads.bundle.js:18565:15)
    at DebugAppView.detectChanges (https://tahseen.github.io/angular2-reactive-form-webpack-esnext/loads.bundle.js:18671:45)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (https://tahseen.github.io/angular2-reactive-form-webpack-esnext/loads.bundle.js:18591:20)
    at DebugAppView._View_FormComponent_Host0.detectChangesInternal (FormComponent.ngfactory.js:31:8)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (https://tahseen.github.io/angular2-reactive-form-webpack-esnext/loads.bundle.js:18565:15)
    at DebugAppView.detectChanges (https://tahseen.github.io/angular2-reactive-form-webpack-esnext/loads.bundle.js:18671:45)
    at ViewRef_.detectChanges (https://tahseen.github.io/angular2-reactive-form-webpack-esnext/loads.bundle.js:16397:66)
```

Here is my code:

**form.component.js**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/common';

import template from './form.component.html'

@Component({
    selector: 'load-form',
    template: template
})
export class FormComponent {
    carriers = [];
    stations = [];
    loadForm = {};

    constructor(formBuilder : FormBuilder) {
        this.formBuilder = formBuilder;

        this.loadForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            carrierId: '',
            carrierStationId: ''
        });

        console.log("constructor")
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("ngOnInit")
    }

    saveLoad(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
}
```

**form.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="loadForm" (ngSubmit)="saveLoad(loadForm.value)">
  <div>
    <label>Carrier</label>
    <div>
      <input type="text" formControlName="carrierId">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label>Station</label>
    <div>
      <input type="text" formControlName="carrierStationId">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <button type="submit" >[+] Add Load</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Has anyone know what is going to here? I stuck on this for days now.

The full code can be found here:

https://github.com/tahseen/angular2-reactive-form-webpack-esnext

And the live example with error can be seen here:

https://tahseen.github.io/angular2-reactive-form-webpack-esnext/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted this on the angular github. They developer over there were able to solved it for me.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11171#issuecomment-243583467

> It looks like there are a few things going on in your sample:
>
> 1) You don't need to add REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES or FormProviders to
>   your module definition. These are included when you import the
>   ReactiveFormsModule.
>
> 2) You are importing a few symbols from @angular/common. That's where
>   the old API lives, and it's not compatible with the new API. If you
>   change the FormBuilder import in your form component file to point to
>   the new API in @angular/forms, the form loads as expected.

Answer (score 10):

I was getting the same issue with Angular 2 - reactive forms approach. My issue was with syntax when binding the main FormGroup to HTML.

I was doing `<form formGroup="myFormGroupName">` instead of `<form [formGroup]="myFormGroupName"/>`. Hope it helps.

Comment: `formGroup="foo"` is not incorrect syntax and works [as seen in the docs](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#step-2-making-a-field-required). Also, as long as you're not dealing with XHTML, don't end your tags with `<form />` as if they were void.

Comment: I was experiencing the same issue and this helped me in my case. Thank you !!!

Comment: After being stuck for 3 days. Thanks @anish

Answer (score 3):

I think, Define a form ID, form ID and Form Group name should not be the same
ex:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right. I encountered a similar problem, however, with respect the latest of Angular 2 at this point of writing, I placed the routes in a separate typescript file. And then, in the app.module.ts added the following line:

`RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES)` to the list of imports `@NgModules`, where `APP_ROUTES` is the array of path routes(imported). And note that you have to place the aforementioned line before the ReactiveFormsModule import.